# Section 2 E, problem (b) Kelley

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I think I finally managed to prove this exercise from Kelley's general topology on page 77.
I would appreciate feedback on it.

> Let $X$ be the set of all pairs of $\Bbb N_0$ with the topology described as follows:
> For each point $(m,n)$ other than $(0,0)$ the set $\{(m,n)\}$ is open.
> A set $U$ is a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ *iff* for all except a finite number of integers $m$ the set $\{n:(m,n)\notin U\} $ is finite.
> (Visualizing $X$ in the Euclidean plane, a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ contains all but a finite number of the members of all but a finite number of columns.)

> (b) Each point of $X$ is the intersection of a countable family of closed neghbourhoods

*Proof*
Since any point other than $(0,0)$ is open, complement of the union of all open points is $(0,0)$. Hence it is closed.
So let $(a,b)$ be any point in $X$, let $\mathcal U$ be a countable family of neighbourhoods of $(0,0)$ s.t:

- Every member of $\mathcal U$ contains $(a,b)$;
- each member excludes finite amount of columns and finite points from column of $(a,b)$ which no other member excludes.

Then $\cap^\infty \{U:\, U\in\mathcal U\}  = (a,b).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a few problems. I think that you have the right idea for showing that $\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ is the intersection of a countable family of closed nbhds of $\langle 0,0\rangle$, but you’ve not stated it very clearly. For convenience let $D=X\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$. For each $\langle m,n\rangle\in D$ let $$U(m,n)=X\setminus\{\langle m,n\rangle\}\;;$$ $U(m,n)$ is a nbhd of $\langle 0,0\rangle$, and since the point $\{\langle m,n\rangle\}$ is open, $U(m,n)$ is closed set. Clearly the family $\{U(m,n):\langle m,n\rangle\in D\}$ is countable, and

$$\begin{align*}
&\bigcap\big\{U(m,n):\langle m,n\rangle\in X\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\big\}\\
&\quad=\bigcap\big\{X\setminus\{\langle m,n\rangle\}:\langle m,n\rangle\in X\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\big\}\\
&\quad=X\setminus\bigcup\big\{\{\langle m,n\rangle\}:\langle m,n\rangle\in X\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\big\}\\
&\quad=X\setminus(X\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\})\\
&\quad=\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ is the intersection of a countable family of closed nbhds of $\langle 0,0\rangle$.

Your argument for the other points, however, definitely does not work: the members of your family $\mathscr{U}$ are all nbhds of $\langle 0,0\rangle$, so their intersection contains $\langle 0,0\rangle$ and therefore **cannot** be $\{\langle a,b\rangle\}$.

> Note that in any case the intersection is a **set**, not a point. If you had a family $\mathscr{U}$ that actually worked, its intersection would still not be $\langle a,b\rangle$: it would be $\{\langle a,b\rangle\}$, the set whose only member is the point $\langle a,b\rangle$.

In fact if $\langle m,n\rangle\in D$, all you need to do is let $V=\{\langle m,n\rangle\}$ and let $\mathscr{V}=\{V\}$. Certainly $V$ is a nbhd of $\langle m,n\rangle$, $\mathscr{V}$ is countable, and $\bigcap\mathscr{V}=\{\langle m,n\rangle\}$, so it only remains to verify that $V$ is a **closed nbhd** of $\langle m,n\rangle$. But $V=X\setminus U(m,n)$, and we already observed that $U(m,n)$ is open nbhd, so $V$ is closed, and we’re done.

Comment: Very constructive feedback, thank you! I have one issue in this post though:

Comment: >...the members of your family $\mathscr{U}$ are all nbhds of $\langle 0,0\rangle$ so their intersection contains $\langle 0,0\rangle$ ...   
Why can't we have for integer $m=0$ an element $0$ in $\{n: \langle m,n \rangle \notin U\}$? The definition does not seem to state that $\langle 0,0 \rangle$ *has* to be element of the nbhd.

Comment: There is a typo in last line in "...that $U(m,n)$ is open...". It is closed, hence V is open.

Comment: @flowian: No, it says exactly what I intended: we need $V$ to be a **closed** nbhd of $\langle m,n\rangle$, and one way to show that is to observe that $U(m,n)$, its complement, is open.

Comment: @flowian: You wrote: ‘let $\mathcal{U}$ be a countable family of neighbourhoods of $(0,0)$’, so **by definition** every member of that family contains $\langle 0,0\rangle$.

Comment: I'm still not convinced about neighbourhoods. The author defines nbhd of $(0,0)$ as follows
"A set $U$ is a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ *iff* for all except a finite number of integers $m$ the set $\{n:(m,n) \notin U\}$ is finite. "   

So if $m=0$ and $n$ is $0$ in the finite set, then $(0,0)\notin U$, and $U$ is a nbhd of $(0,0)$.

Comment: you wrote "we already observed that $U(m,n)$ is open, so $V$ is closed".
But you observed that $U(m,n)$ is **closed**. This confuses me.

Comment: @flowian: $U(m,n)$ is open **by the definition of the topology**: it’s a basic open nbhd of $\langle 0,0\rangle$. I had to **prove** that it is also closed. Your previous comment shows that you don’t understand what it means to say that some set $U$ is a nbhd of some point $p$: for some people it means that $U$ is an open set containing $p$, and for some it means that $U$ contains an open set that contains $p$, but for everyone it implies that $p\in U$. The fact that $U(m,n)$ is a nbhd of $\langle 0,0\rangle$ **by definition** means that $\langle 0,0\rangle\in U(m,n)$. That overrides ...

Comment: ... any other consideration. (By the way, in this case *neighbourhood of* $p$ means *open set containing* $p$.)

Comment: Yes, I know the standard definition of nbhd. Can you kindly explain why the standard definition overrides the particular definition in this example?

Comment: @flowian: The person who wrote the definition assumed that every reader would understand that a nbhd of a point always contains that point. That is something so basic that it would not occur to most of us that anyone might misunderstand.

Comment: Except maybe for student just learning!

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I will review the whole thing in the morning!

Comment: @flowian: You’re welcome.

Comment: Got it. My confusion lied in mixing *sets* with *nbhds*. I suggested edit to the answer for easier reading.